# Change theme without delay in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using of provider to change theme in my app. My app initialize first with dark theme.

```
class ThemeNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String key = "them";
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  bool _darkTheme;

  bool get darkTheme => _darkTheme;

  ThemeNotifier() {
    _darkTheme = true;
    _loadFromPrefs();
  }

  toggleTheme() {
    _darkTheme = !_darkTheme;
    _saveToPrefs();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  _loadFromPrefs() async {
    await _initPrefs();
    _darkTheme = _prefs.getBool(key) ?? true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  _saveToPrefs() async {
    await _initPrefs();
    _prefs.setBool(key, _darkTheme);
  }

  _initPrefs() async {
    if (_prefs == null) _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
}
```

When i changed them to light i call `toggleTheme` method and i change  _darkTheme to false.

I use above codes like this:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: ThemeNotifier(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(
        builder: (context, notifire, child) {
          child:
          return MaterialApp(
            title: "theme",
            theme: notifire.darkTheme ? dark : light,
            home: HomeScreen(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but when i change app with light theme and do hot reload application for just a second my app theme is dark and then changed into light mode.

How could i load application without dark mode when i use light mode?that is mean when i change them to light mode i do not want to show dark mode even for a few millisecond ?

Comment: Try this  ThemeNotifier() {
    _loadFromPrefs();
  } instead of   ThemeNotifier() {
    _darkTheme = true;
    _loadFromPrefs();
  }

Comment: if i do that , i got error I/flutter (10261): The following assertion was thrown building Consumer<ThemeNotifier>(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter (10261): [_DefaultInheritedProviderScope<ThemeNotifier>]):
I/flutter (10261): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null @FederickJonathan

Comment: @sayreskabir same problem here. were you able to find a solution?

Comment: In release mode, It's Ok.

Comment: It looks like you followed this [tutorial](https://codesource.io/building-theme-switcher-using-provider-and-shared-preferences/). I did the same and ran into the very same problem that you have. What have you done in particular to make it work?

Comment: For anyone interested, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47644516/2402281) gives an indication why the `--release` flag does not cause the error mentioned by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> How could i load application without dark mode when i use light mode?that is mean when i change them to light mode i do not want to show dark mode even for a few millisecond ?

When you do not want to have the dark mode shown for a few milliseconds, you have two options:

**Option 1:** You should wait for the `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` in a `FutureBuilder` in your `MaterialApp` and show a loading screen. The loading screen will be themed with either light or dark unless you theme the loading screen independent of the theme from shared preferences.

**Option 2:** This option is less user-friendly, because it will block any rendering for said few milliseconds until your shared preferences are loaded. In your `main.dart` in your `main` function, you can do the following:

```
void main() {
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then(() => runApp(MyApp()));
}
```

or

```
void main() async {
    await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Regarding your comment

> I/flutter (10261): The following assertion was thrown building Consumer(dirty, dependencies: I/flutter (10261): [_DefaultInheritedProviderScope]): I/flutter (10261): Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

I wrote that I had the same error. In my case, that error really originated from somewhere in my `build` method and it was fairly hard to track it down. I'd suggest to use `ChangeNotifierProvider(create: ThemeNotifier(), ...` over `ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ThemeNotifier(), ...`. For details, please review [this very datailed SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861315/2402281).

My hunch is that your assertion error stems from the line `theme: notifire.darkTheme ? dark : light,` in your `MaterialApp` and it might get fixed if you change your provider to create your change notifier instead of reusing an existing one. Adding the `--release` flag really is nothing more than a mere workaround to ignore this instability within your app.